# Convert Decimal to Binary in c++ with correct Bit Size

Tags: c++, arrays, string, binary, decimal

I am writing a program that takes in numbers entered by a user and stores them into an array. The program will then convert the values to decimal and store in a new array. I am having trouble converting the binary value into the correct bit size.

For example a user enters `3` and `4`.
My program stores and converts them to binary resulting in `11` and `100`. How can I get it to store `011` and `100`?

I believe I'll need to convert to a char array or a string of some sort but I have no idea what steps I should follow.

Comment: You can use std::string binary = std::bitset<8>(num).to_string(); here 8 represents the length of the binary that you need and num is the num passed by the user.

Comment: You are giving the correct output if 3 is 11 it is still still the same as 011 so I don't see the point to do it. Think about it as your  problem is that you never know how high number the user type and how many zeros you want to add. To conclude the thing you want to do is pointless.

Comment: Unless you're using a 3-bit bit field you can't store only three bits, and even if you are you're still storing in binary, where `11` == `011`. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you’re trying to do is this:

```
void Convert(int Number, char *Array, int Bits) {
   int Bit;

   for (Bit = 0; Bit < Bits; Bit++) {
      if ((Number & (1 << (Bits - (Bit + 1)))) > 0) {
         Array[Bit] = '1';
      } else {
         Array[Bit] = '0';
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did almost same thing as given below:

You can try this.

```
//Decimal to Binary
char* dTb(int num, unsigned bit)
{
    char *binStr = new char (bit + 1);
    int len = bit;

    binStr[bit] = '\0';
    while (bit--)   binStr[bit] = '0';

    if (num == 0)
        return binStr;

    int r;
    while (num && len)
    {
        r = num % 2;
        binStr[--len] = r + '0';
        num /= 2;
    }

    return binStr;
}
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Don’t you mean `char *binStr = new char [bit + 1];`?